# Seguir trabajando mientras se ejecuta selenium

Tags: c#, web, selenium

Intento que al ejecutar un botón se abra selenium, sin embargo trabaja en el mismo hilo que el form, por lo tanto como puedo hacer para poder seguir trabajando el form, este es el codigo

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("ElElemento]")).Click();
driver.close();
```